# how to start outline-minor-mode with latex-mode?

Tags: latex, outline-mode

I have the following in my `.emacs`:

```
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook #'outine-minor-mode)
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
          (outline-minor-mode 1)))
```

(I am aware this redundant, I am just trying to demonstrate that neither method works). Yet, when I open a `*.tex` file I see the following upon executing `C-h m`:

```
Enabled minor modes: Auto-Composition Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption         
Column-Number File-Name-Shadow Font-Lock Global-Font-Lock
Global-Hl-Line Global-Linum Line-Number Linum Mouse-Wheel Openwith   
Override-Global Tex-Pdf Tool-Bar Tooltip Transient-Mark

(Information about these minor modes follows the major mode info.)
LaTeX/P mode defined in `tex-site.el':
Major mode in AUCTeX for editing LaTeX files.
See info under AUCTeX for full documentation.
```

I understand from the above list of minor modes that the `outline-minor-mode` has not turned on. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`latex-mode-hook` is the hook for the default Emacs latex mode. You appear to be using AUCTeX, which uses the hook `LaTeX-mode-hook` (note capitalization). More info in the [AUCTeX manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Modes-and-Hooks.html).

Answer (score 0):

You're using AUCTex.  According to the documentation (section 5.1, use C-h i m auctex [RET] to read it in emacs), the hook name for AUCtex is actually `LaTeX-mode-hook`.

So just use instead

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'outline-minor-mode)
```

The hook `latex-mode-hook` also exists (see section 25.10.4 of emacs manual) but is used by emacs native tex/latex mode (when AUCTex is not loaded).  This is arguably confusing.